# Why does CharacterBody2D jump when in motion?

Tags: c#, godot, godot4

I've this `CharacterBody2D` subtype:

```cs
using Godot;
using System;
using Recoyx.CarKnockOnline;

public partial class AutomobileEntity : CharacterBody2D
{
    public PlayerData PlayerData = null;

    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {
    }

    // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm playing around with it by calling `MoveAndCollide` on the `_Process` subroutine of my game screen:

```cs
// Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
public override void _Process(double delta)
{
    this.MainPlayerEntity.MoveAndCollide(new Vector2(2f, 2f));
}
```

... where `this.MainPlayerEntity` is an instance of the `AutomobileEntity` type above. The motion works, but it has unexpected constant jumps (laggy GIF recorder, so you'll see only few):

[image: Constant jumps]

The `CharacterBody2D` in question has `motionMode = grounded`. I tried `motionMode = floating` as well. I've also tried tweaking the `velocity` property of the `CharacterBody2D` and using this same method for moving the entity.

Why does the `CharacterBody2D` keep jumping?

#### `MoveAndSlide`

I did also try `MoveAndSlide` and it keeps constantly jumping with velocity `(212, 212)`.

Comment: Just do `motion * ((float) delta)` and pass it to `move_and_collide` or assign it to `velocity`.